# Count numbers in jsonata objects

Tags: json, object, count, sum, jsonata

can someone help me, because i am in sadness because it did not work out. Json values ​​about employees are passed to the date object, then the condition of their choice is fulfilled, if everything is true in the condition, then 1 is entered in the cnti field, if not, then nothing is entered. As a result, if two people satisfy the condition, then I display two 1 (1 and 1). How can I count the number of 1 and output their number as a result.

Below I will show you how it works.

This is json code

```
"schedules":[
    {
        "user": {
            "id": 1111,
            "email": "aaa@gmail.com",
            "role": "user",
            "profile": {
                "lastName": "test",
                "firstName": "test",
                "fullName": "test",
                "position": "salesman",
                "restaurant": 1111,
                "phone": "+66456464",
                "trainee": null,

                "__typename": "UserProfile"
            },
            "isActive": true,
            "documents": [],
            "__typename": "User"
        },
        "events": [
            {
                "userId": 1111,
                "eventId": 11111111,
                
                "type": "Shift",
                "position": null,
                "restaurantId": 222222,
                "state": "PUBLISHED",
                "__typename": "UserEvent"
            },
            {
                "userId": 1111,
                "eventId": 11111111,
                "type": "Shift",
                "position": null,
                "restaurantId": 222222,
                "state": "PUBLISHED",
                "__typename": "UserEvent"
            }
        ],
        "__typename": "UserSchedule"
    },
    {
        "user": {
            "id": 1111
            "email": "aaa@gmail.com",
            "role": "user",
            "profile": {
                "lastName": "test",
                "firstName": "test",
                "fullName": "test",
                "position": "salesman",
                "restaurant": 1111,
                "phone": "+66456464",
                "trainee": null,

                "__typename": "UserProfile"
            },
            "isActive": true,
            "documents": [],
            "__typename": "User"
        },
        "events": [
            {
                "userId": 1111,
                "eventId": 11111111,
                
                "type": "Shift",
                "position": null,
                "restaurantId": 222222,
                "state": "PUBLISHED",
                "__typename": "UserEvent"
            },
            {
                "userId": 1111,
                "eventId": 11111111,
                "type": "Shift",
                "position": null,
                "restaurantId": 222222,
                "state": "PUBLISHED",
                "__typename": "UserEvent"
            }
        ],
        "__typename": "UserSchedule"
    }
]
```

and now i show a piece of code in jsonata which handles that json

```
(
  
  $selectedDate := selectedDate;
  $from := $moment(from).clone().add($selectedDate, 'day');
  $to := $from.clone().add(0,'day');
  $dayMillis := 24 * 3600000;
  $all := 1;

  $dayNum := $floor($to.diff($from) / $dayMillis);
  $days := [0..$dayNum].($n:=$; $from.clone().add($n,'day')).{
    "dayOfMonth": format('D'),
    "dayOfWeek": format('dd'),
    "from": $from,
    "to": $to 
  };
  

  $restaurant := $query('query restaurant($id: Int!) { restaurant(id: $id) { id title address } }', {"id": restaurant}).restaurant;
  $user := $query('query currentUser { currentUser { id profile { firstName lastName patronymic position } }}', {}).currentUser;
  $q := 'query schedules($filter: FilterSchedulesInput) {
    schedules(filter: $filter) {
      user {
        id
        profile {
          lastName
          firstName
          patronymic
          position 
        }
      }
      events {
        eventId
        beginAt
        endAt
        type
        position
        details
        restaurantId
        state
      }
    }
  }';
 
  $schedules := $query($q,
    { 
      "filter": {
        "restaurant": restaurant,
        "from": $from.clone().startOf('day').toISOString(),
        "to": $from.clone().endOf('day').toISOString(),
        "filter": null
      } 
    }).schedules;


  {
  
    "days": $days,
    "from": $from.format('DD.MM.YYYY'),
    "to": $to.format('DD.MM.YYYY'),
    "restaurant": $restaurant,
    "userName": user.profile.lastName & ' ' & $substring($user.profile.firstName, 0, 1) & '.' & $substring($user.profile.patronymic, 0, 1) & '.',
    
    
    

    "data": $schedules.(
      $events := events[type='Смена']~>|$|{
          "details": details ? $eval(details), 
          "hours": $round(($toMillis(endAt) - $toMillis(beginAt))/3600000 + 0.5),
          "date": $substring(beginAt, 0, 10),
          "all" : $all,
          "position" : position,
          "dateAt": beginAt,
          "dateOut": endAt 
      },['__typename']|;
      $cnti := $events.all;
      $details := $events.details;

      $total := $sum($append([], $events.hours));
      
      { 
          "position": user.profile.position, 
          "det": $details,
          "cnti": $cnti,
          "name": user.profile.lastName & ' ' & $substring($user.profile.firstName, 0, 1) & '.' & $substring($user.profile.patronymic, 0, 1) & '.',
          "total": $total,

          )
 
      };
    )^(name)
    
  };
  
  
)
```

in the code above i added comments that can explain you how it works. i tried to add string like $total(sum all numbers from cnti, but it didn't work)

and it is code for html document in which I output 1

```
<div>
      <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <tr>
          <th>Проверка</th> 
          <th>{{#each data}}{{cnti}}{{/if}}{{/each}}</th>
        </tr> 
        <tr>
          <th>Trading point</th>
          <th></th>
        </tr> 
  </table>
  </div>
```

that is the picture of result i got(first image)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/27tFn.png)

that is the result i need(second image)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mxanb.png)

Comment: Hey @Zerono, I think you have not provided the full input JSON document, and I see some missing variable definitions in your JSONata code snippet: $schedules, $moment, etc. Do you mind providing a full input JSON document example and an expected output from it?

From what I can gather from your message though, here's an example where $cnti returns `1` for an example document that you provided: https://stedi.link/UBBioy0

Comment: If you have to deal with possibility that there might be more than one entry in the `events` object - consider using `$reduce` function: https://stedi.link/7iCPJ89

Comment: @mralex i chenged it, it is ok?

Comment: @mralex and what should i do if i want to add all the numbers

Comment: @mralex если хотите, то можно перейти на русский язык